# Every "last" one of them

Tags: phrase-meaning

Heard this sentence in a movie:

> And every last one of them trying to achieve it all.

What's the difference between the phrases:

- Every last one of them
- Every one of them
- Each one of them

Comment: every last x of y is just an emphatic way of saying it. And generally, spoken not written.

Comment: The question [Where did the expression “every last one” come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33834/) was asked on ELU several years ago. But nobody can really explain exactly how ***last*** came to be there. It's just a "fixed idiomatic expression" that's generally seen as more emphatic. As to ***every one*** and ***each one***, they're just equivalent ways of saying the same thing (but note that we *don't* normally say ***each last one of them***).

Comment: Guys, can you put your really good answers into the field for answers, please?

Comment: @FumbleFingers your comment was helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @tenebris2020 If you see a good comment, copy/paste it into an answer and reap the reward for yourself.  Usually I add a couple of examples where helpful, and give credit to the person who wrote the comment, but otherwise it's a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: @Andrew I'm lazy and not greedy. Go ahead and do what you advised me to do; maybe I'll do it another time :)